# py to apk using Google Colab

Tags: python, android, kivy

Am trying to convert a .py application to an apk file using Google Colab but I keep encountering this error:

```
[DEBUG]:    ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement kivy-deps.angle (from versions: none)
[DEBUG]:    ERROR: No matching distribution found for kivy-deps.angle
```

I am using Python 3.9.9 and Kivy version 2.1.0 and  I have installed all Kivy packages but each time I try converting my .py file to apk using Google Colab am getting the above mentioned error

Here is the requirements for my .py application

```
C:\Users\26095\Desktop\TEQ_ANDROID>pip show kivy
Name: Kivy
Version: 2.1.0
Summary: A software library for rapid development of hardware-accelerated multitouch applications.
Home-page: http://kivy.org
Author: Kivy Team and other contributors
Author-email: kivy-dev@googlegroups.com
License: MIT
Location: c:\users\26095\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages
Requires: docutils, kivy-deps.angle, kivy-deps.glew, kivy-deps.sdl2, Kivy-Garden, pygments, pypiwin32
Required-by:
```

Here is part of my bulldozer.spec file where I have added all the requirements

```
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3, kivy, docutils, kivy-deps.angle, kivy-deps.glew, kivy-deps.sdl2, Kivy-Garden, pygments, pypiwin32
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting pillow in the requirements, it might work.

requirements = python3, kivy, docutils, kivy-deps.angle, kivy-deps.glew, kivy-deps.sdl2, Kivy-Garden, pygments, pypiwin32, pillow

Comment: Hey Tom thanks for your response, I have added pillow to the requirements but am still encountering the same error

Answer (score 0):

Kivy 2.1.0 officially supports Python versions 3.7 - 3.10.
https://kivy.org/doc/stable/gettingstarted/installation.html

Kivy doesnt support Python3.10. If so try to downgrade to 3.9.x and it should work